# HTML reports on GitHub Actions / GitHub pull requests

Tags: github, report, pull-request, github-actions

Is there any possible way to show pretty HTML reports (from test runners like Jest, Mocha, Cypress, test coverage, etc.) on GitHub's pull requests checks?

Answer (score 5):

Any chance you could accomplish what you're looking for with Job Summaries?

https://github.blog/2022-05-09-supercharging-github-actions-with-job-summaries/

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-job-summary

If you need something in the actual PR, it's possible to write your own Github Action that will comment/update based on the data you determine. Take a look at the Github Actions Toolkit, specifically `@actions/github`:

https://github.com/actions/toolkit

Answer (score 2):

This might solve your problem:
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/html-preview

```
- name: HTML Preview
  id: html_preview
  uses: pavi2410/html-preview-action@v2
  with:
    html_file: 'index.html'
```

It seems to be using this (https://github.com/htmlpreview/htmlpreview.github.com), so it might not work that well with private repos.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not solution but work around.
GitHub Actions has next action: `actions/upload-artifact` https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact

So you can export your reports as artifacts and then download them. Probably if it's public repo, you can download them via API, but nothing out-of-box... so good luck ...

Comment: Hi Max, is there any other way to this question, or it's still the same after a year?

Comment: Nothing to be honest

Answer (score 1):

> Is it any possibility to show pretty html reports (from test runners like Jest, Mocha, Cypress, test coverage, etc.) on GitHub pull requests checks?

Q2, 2023: not in this way (from a third-party tool to a GitHub PR checks)

For instance, [`cypress-io/github-action`](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action#parallel) allows triggering tests through GitHub Action, and present the result nicely

```yaml
on: push
jobs:
  test:
    name: Cypress run
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    strategy:
      # when one test fails, DO NOT cancel the other
      # containers, because this will kill Cypress processes
      # leaving Cypress Cloud hanging ...
      # https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action/issues/48
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        # run 3 copies of the current job in parallel
        containers: [1, 2, 3]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # because of "record" and "parallel" parameters
      # these containers will load balance all found tests among themselves
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        with:
          record: true
          parallel: true
          group: 'Actions example'
        env:
          # pass the Cypress Cloud record key as an environment variable
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
          # Recommended: pass the GitHub token lets this action correctly
          # determine the unique run id necessary to re-run the checks
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

[image: https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action/raw/master/images/parallel.png]

But that is triggering a third-party tool from GitHub, and getting the result to said tool.
You would not get the same result in a PR check.